# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar 3 dígitos de un campo numérico con Python?

Tags: python

Quiero mostrar los primeros 3 dígitos de un campo numérico denominado `DNI`.
Digamos que el `DNI = '132648789547'` y solo quiero mostrar --> `DNI = 132`.
¿Alguien puede decirme y escribirlo con código?

Comment: Si es un numero, `int`, ¿Te sirve: `int(str(DNI)[0:3])`?

Comment: super, gracias amigo

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente declara la variable con el valor de la `dni` y luego defines la posición del caracter:

```
dni='132648789547'
print(str(dni)[:3])
```

Puedes realizarlo con [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) y una [función anónima](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions):

```
dni=['132648789547']
nueva_lista = list(map(lambda x:x[:3], dni))
print(nueva_lista)
```

Otra forma es mediante una cadena, lo que puedes hacer es implementar un ciclo para iterar por cada elemento y hacer el recorte de cada cadena, mediante una comprensión de listas puedes generar una nueva lista de acuerdo al requerimiento:

```
dni=['132648789547']
resultado = [e[:3] for e in dni]
print(resultado)
```

Saludos!